# Ignore page refresh if there are youtube videos inside the page

Tags: jquery, if-statement, page-refresh

I use this script to auto refresh page when users are inactive on my website.

```
<script>
 var time = new Date().getTime();
 $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
     time = new Date().getTime();
 });

 function refresh() {
     if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 60000) 
         window.location.reload(true);
     else 
         setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
 }

 setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
</script>
```

I need to exclude the auto refresh if in my page there are youtube videos. Youtube video are always inside #player CSS id.

Comment: And what's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

By adding `&& !$('#player').length` in the if statement you can check if `#player` is a thing and therefore the video is there. So it only refreshes if it isnt there.

```
<script>
 var time = new Date().getTime();
 $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
     time = new Date().getTime();
 });

 function refresh() {
     if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 60000 && !$('#player').length) 
         window.location.reload(true);
    else 
         setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
 }

 setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I use it, but my website crash. Maybe this rule generate too many request..

Answer (score 0):

You can set a conditional in javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById('player')) {

    [... CODE HERE ...]

}
```

Comment: I use it, but my WordPress site crash. Maybe too many request with this conditional.